# cocos2d load random image from sprite sheet

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I am conceptualizing for a game I want to make and have played a little bit but ran in to a problem.  I am learning iOS programming and learning cocos2d also.

I have about 20 images.  They are all the same size 64x64.  Basically they are grouped as 5 different shapes (square, circle, etc.) each in 5 different colors.  What I want to be able to do, is randomly drop them down the screen in portrait.  There will only ever be one per column falling.  There can be duplicates across the screen, I actually want that.  While it is random, I want to control the introduction of a new color.

I have been really racking my brain to figure out how to do this.  As I said, I am pretty new to this so any help would be really great.

If I could be so bold, can any answers be in a format to "Explain it like <strike>I'm 5</strike> I have only been doing this for about 1 year"

Comment: Well if I group the images in 5 groups of 5, say A.1-A.5, B.1-B.5,...E.5 then I want to say control when a new letter (color group) is allowed to be an option.  I am not worried to much about the algorithm to do that, what I can not figure out is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look at this [tutorial about sprites sheets](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d): it will show you how to create your sprite sheets and load them into memory.
(Since the tutorial aims at building an animation, you can skip points 4 and 5).

Now, if you have your sprite sheets in place, what you do to create a sprite is:

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"frameName.png"];
```

and then you can add it to your layer/scene.

About the random selection: you can keep a list of image names (say, an `NSArray`) and then randomly (i.e., use `srand` to generate a random index) select the `@"frameName.png"` value from it.

Comment: So I can used say an array of just string names then dereference them "...spriteWithSpriteFrameName:arrayOfImageNames[randomIndex]];"?

Comment: that is what I was trying to suggest. If you use `spriteWithSpriteFrameName`, it is the most natural way of doing it, IMO. If you want to partition your images based on their color, the best option would be using an NSDictionary where you store for each color name (string), an NSArray (or plain c-array if you prefer) with the images for that color. Then you choose randomly, first the color among the dictionary keys, then the image of that color in the array associated to that key.

Comment: Oooo I like that NSDictionary thing.  Should I load all of the images and just set them invisible (which would be 25 x 10 columns) or should I dynamically load them so that there are only 10 images loaded at a time?  I guess the question I have is whether there is a bigger performance hit of changing a texture associated with a sprite or having a lot of sprites loaded.

Comment: you only have to worry about the 20 different images you have, not about their "replication" in sprites (textures are cached). 20 64x64 images would fit a 512x512 sheet (open GL texture sizes go with powers of two) and this will be no problem memory-wise, so you can "preload" them.

Answer (score 0):

When using Cocos2D the best way to use sprites is with Sprite Sheets. That is, a combination of two type of files:

1. A plist file with all the coordinates of N sprites and all different data about the sprites, size, name, etc.
2. A png file with all the sprites

You can make a sprite sheet with different types of software, like:

- Zwoptex
- Sprite Helper
- Sprite Packer
- Sprite Master
- Texture Packer

About performance, when using a sprite sheet you will need to use CCSpriteBatchNode, as the API documentation states ([read here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_sprite_batch_node.html)):

> A **CCSpriteBatchNode** can reference one and only one texture (one image file, one texture atlas). Only the CCSprites that are contained in that texture can be added to the CCSpriteBatchNode. All CCSprites added to a CCSpriteBatchNode are drawn in one OpenGL ES draw call. **If the CCSprites are not added to a CCSpriteBatchNode then an OpenGL ES draw call will be needed for each one, which is less efficient.**

THe code to use Sprite Sheet:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprite.plist"];

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprite.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];
```

Hope this helps.